# Why use a getter without a setter?

Tags: c#

No this has not been answered, stop being so fast on the down voting and read, this is why NOT to have a setter accompanying a getter. What you guys have sent so far is how a getter and setter work hand in hand and not why one would have them individually.

What is the point of only having a getter that is not accompanied by a setter?
As far as I understand it, we use the getter to get the value and a setter to validate the value inserted.

But I have this code here that leaves me confused.

```
private int Area { get { return _width * _height } }
```

What's the point?
Nothing is being validated.
Why not just make a field holding the value, such as:

```
private int area = _width * _height
```

Confusing to say the least.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property

Comment: In simple terminology, That variable wouldn't be updated.. Where as the getter would be recalculated upon being called.

Comment: -Adriani6, good point. That has to be why, thanks man.

Comment: Additionally, having an extra field takes more memory per instance, just for redundant information. (Sometimes that's appropriate, if the redundant information is expensive to compute, but definitely not always.)

Comment: Both getter and setter can serve __various__ purposes in addition to getting and setting. Validation is one, setting dependent fields another.. Having no setter can make the variable readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many advantages of writing this instead of a field:

```
private int Area { get { return _width * _height; } }
```

- `Area` does not have to be manually updated every time `_width` or `_height` changes. You might forget to update it in some places.
- `Area` won't be accidentally assigned another (incorrect) value. If you try to set this, the compiler will stop you.
- Having an extra field requires more memory to be allocated *as long as the instances are alive*. Having a getter like this only costs a little time computing the product of two numbers *when you access the property*. Since this is only a multiplication, the time it takes here is really, really little.

More generally, you might see some types whose properties are all get-only, such as `DateTime`. This is done so that the type is immutable, and immutability is good. See [Why do we need immutable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769607/why-do-we-need-immutable-class).